# Using a Wrapper Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote some code for an application that uses the following pattern:

```
function _getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(_hasDataTypeA()) {
            SomeBackendAccessObject.getTypeAData().then(resolve, reject);
        } else {
            SomeBackendAccessObject.getTypeBData().then(_convertToTypeA).then(resolve, reject);
        }
    });
}
```

My rationale for writing the code this way is that if `_hasDataTypeA` throws an exception, we're still able to return a Promise. This means the caller doesn't have to do a `try` block *and* a Promise `.catch`; but this code feels smelly to me. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, are you saying that `_hasDataTypeA` can throw an exception, or did you mean that it can return `false`?

Comment: @konijn Yes, I'm saying `_hasDataTypeA` could, hypothetically, throw an exception.

Comment: So what should happen in that case ?

Comment: @konjin (I think) I would like a Promise to catch the error so that the caller of `_getData` can see it by calling `.catch`, but I'm not entirely confident in this premise either.

Comment: @konijn Did you want to try to put an answer? You can get some bounty even if the answer isn't accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that your fulfilling the wrapper promise by way of other promises inside it. Seems like and extra step that isn't needed. Especially the final `.then(resolve, reject)` feels like a big anti-pattern especially since it is a repeated pattern. So the rational is to catch the exception. My take on this is to wrap only `_hasDataTypeA` in it's own promise and then use that result to manage the following promises:

```
function _hasDataTypeAPromised() {
  try {
    return Promise.resolve(_hasDataTypeA());
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}

function _getData() {
  return _hasDataTypeAPromised()
    .then(function(hasDataTypeA) {
      if(hasDataTypeA) {
        return SomeBackendAccessObject.getTypeAData();
      } else {
        return SomeBackendAccessObject.getTypeBData();
      }
    });
}
```

You could even ternary-ize the method with:

```
var method = hasDataTypeA ? 'getTypeAData' : 'getTypeBData';
return SomeBackendAccessObject[method]();
```

Comment: `getTypeAData` and `getTypeBData` return promises, so you don't need to wrap them at the end.

Comment: I call `then` on the return value of `SomeBackendAccessObject.getTypeAData()`.